# StoreKit framework - Callback not called when Changing iTunes store for in app purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I have an issue with StoreKit framework and switching countries

I'm trying the following scenario on iOS.

> 1. Login to Settings, using Apple developer account A. It changes the Store to Country 1 and takes me to App Store
> 2. Go back to Settings and remove account(App store country is still A)
> 3. Load the app where payments are enabled and try to do an in app purchase
> 4. Use a test account B which is valid only for purchases in country B.
> 5. While using the test account, I get a confirmation that I will be switched to Country B in the App store and I'm taken to the app store
> 6. After I resume the app, the SKPaymentQueue's updatedTransactions callback isn't being called that it failed.

Is there anyway I can deduct this event and show an appropriate error message ? Thanks!

Comment: I faced this problem too, although it won't happen very often in real life but at least app must be able to handle it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar things happen before. My guess is that at some point, someone used your sandbox account B to log into iTunes somewhere; most likely in the Settings -> iTunes screen on a device. In-App Purchase sandbox accounts become invalid if they're ever used to log in to iTunes; the only way to use them is to provide the username/password within the application, after attempting to start a purchase. My recommendation is to use iTunesConnect to make a new sandbox account, and use iTunesConnect to set its country affiliation, and make sure no one ever uses it to log into iTunes.

Comment: I tried the same steps with Candy Crush(although with real accounts this time) and they seem to handle it. So my guess is, there is some callback that gets triggered somewhere. I'm not sure which one

Comment: I've written IAP code, I'm not aware of any such API. I wish you the best of luck with this problem.